# Bootstrap4: Table using the whole width but still using table-responsive

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

Would it be possible to use table-responsive that only use the minimal column width based on the length of the data in the column, and also having the `thead` using all the canvas width.

**Example**: (the last column that has no content would use the remaining space on the right)

[image]

Comment: you can make table responsive by `overflow-x: scroll` no need to think much for that

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `table-responsive` class to your table, it will occupy 100% of it's parent's width and will space the columns equally... this is shown in the **top** table in the code snippet below

But we can do what you're looking for:

- want all the columns to use minimal width
- last empty column to occupy the remaining width.
- check the **bottom** table in the code snippet below

```css
th {
  background: lightgray
}

.myTableOne td {
  white-space: nowrap
}

.myTableOne th:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h4>Table with table-responsive class</h4> <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table  table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>

<h4>Table for your requirements </h4>
<br/>

<div class="myTableOne">
  <table class=" table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Anna</td>
        <td>Pitt</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```